# How to get the names of the selected songs and display them one by one in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm making a simple music player in HTML, JavaScript and CSS that plays the song/music files locally, in my HTML I have an audio element and 3 buttons (select files, previous song, next song) and a **p** element tag that should display the name of each song that is being played,

Here is my HTML and JavaScript code :

```js
const aud = document.getElementById("aud");

const prv = document.getElementById("prv");

const nxt = document.getElementById("nxt");

let audios = [];

let selectAudio = document.getElementById("select-audio");

//Listen when the select-audio button is clicked to perform the action of selecting the audio files

selectAudio.addEventListener('click', function() {

        //CREATE AN INPUT ELEMENT AND THEN CHECK FOR CHANGE
        const input = document.createElement('input');

        input.type = "file";
        input.accept = "audio/*";
        input.multiple = true;
        input.onchange = function(e) {

            audios = Array.from(e.target.files);
            playAudios(audios, 0); //it's 0 here so that it plays the first audio

            for (let audName = 0; audName < audios.length; audName++) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = input.files[audName].name;
            }



        }; //END OF ONCHANGE FUNCTION OF THE INPUT

        input.click();

    } //END OF THE ADD EVENT LISTENER FUNCTION

); //END OF selectAudio EVENT LISTENER



//Play the Audios, NOTE that the following function was called previousely under the onchange function
// so that it changes once the audio player's value is changed


function playAudios(audios, index) {

    //First let's define a function to play the next audio file
    function nxtAudio() {

        if (index < audios.length - 1) {
            index++
        } else {
            index = 0;
        }
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(audios[index]);
        aud.src = url;
        aud.play();




    } //END OF nxtAudio FUNCTION


    //Next let's define a function to play the previous audio file

    function prvAudio() {

        if (index > 0) {
            index--
        } else {
            index = audios.length - 1;
        }
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(audios[index]);
        aud.src = url;
        aud.play();

    } //END OF prvAudio FUNCTION


    //Listen when the Audio has ENDED

    aud.addEventListener('ended', function() {

            nxtAudio();

        } //END OF THE 'ENDED' FUNCTION
    ); //END OF THE addEventListener


    //LISTEN WHEN THE NEXT BUTTON IS CLICKED
    nxt.addEventListener('click', function() {
        nxtAudio();
    }); //END OF NXT


    //LISTEN WHEN THE PREVIOUS BUTTON IS CLICKED
    prv.addEventListener('click', function() {
        prvAudio();
    }); //END OF PRV


    //START PLAYING THE FIRST AUDIO

    const url = URL.createObjectURL(audios[index]);
    aud.src = url;
    aud.play();


} // THE END OF THE playAudios FUNCTION
```

```html
<button id="select-audio">Select Files</button>
<button id="prv">Previous</button>
<button id="nxt">Next</button>
<audio id="aud" controls></audio>
<p id="title"></p>
```

Now in my JavaScript code I try to get the name of the song and display it using this line (inside a for loop) where audName is the index
`document.getElementById("title").innerHTML=input.files[audName].name`
however the

element only displays the last song in the list without changing it when the song ends or when I click on the next or previous button (note in the following code I didn't place the previous line in the next and previous and end functions, but I tried it, and it didn't work).

I mostly tried the following line
`document.getElementById("title").innerHTML=input.files[audName].name`
I expected the name to be update once the input value changes but nothing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you need to change the title in several places inside your `playAudios()` funcion.

You are currently placing the title change on file upload, but that's not what plays the song.

Inside the playAudios add following function:

```
function setTitle(file) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = file.name
}
```

Then add following line at end (last line before the `}`) of `nxtAudio`, `prvAudio` and `playAudios` functions:

```
    setTitle(audios[index])
```

And remove your for loop after the `playAudios(audios,0)` call

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked  I wasn't able to figure out where I should put the code to get the name of the current index and to make it update once the song changes, thank you so much 

Answer (score 1):

- Name your variables properly, don't eat characters for sake of readability. Same goes for single character variables like the event's `e`. Use rather `evt` or `event`
- Don't unnecessarily comment your code where not needed. Make is simple to read and concise. Like a prose.
- Don't repeat yourself. You're copy pasting the play code three times. Create a single `play()` function instead
- Don't assign event listeners inside event listeners
- There's no need to pass around `audios` as argument to functions if you already use a scoped variable. Functions *will* have access to it regardless
- When using `URL.createObjectURL` don't forget to also use [revokeObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL_static) to free up memory
- To loop-around an index, create a reusable function `mod()` that will do the job for you like: `index = mod(++index, tot)` for *next* and respectively `--` for the *prev* action. (Notice the `prev` instead of `prv` ;))

```js
const el = (sel, par) => (document || par).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);
const mod = (n, m) => ((n % m) + m) % m; // Fix negative Modulo

const elSelectAudio = el("#select-audio");
const elAudio = el("#audio");
const elPrev = el("#prev");
const elNext = el("#next");
const elTitle = el("#title");

let audios = [];
let tot = 0;     // Add this one too
let index = 0;   // Forgot about this guy?

const browse = () => {
  // In-memory input type file for files selection
  elNew("input", {
    type: "file",
    accept: "audio/*",
    multiple: true,
    onchange(evt) {
      audios = [...evt.currentTarget.files];
      tot = audios.length; // Set how many audios we have
      index = 0; // Reset index
      play();    // No need to pass `index` as argument
    }
  }).click();
};

const next = () => {
  index = mod(++index, tot);
  play()
};

const prev = () => {
  index = mod(--index, tot);
  play()
};

const play = () => {
  if (!tot) return; // No audios to play
  URL.revokeObjectURL(elAudio.src); // Don't forget to revoke!
  elAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(audios[index]);
  elTitle.textContent = audios[index].name;
  elAudio.play();
};

// Init:
elSelectAudio.addEventListener("click", browse);
elAudio.addEventListener("ended", next);
elNext.addEventListener("click", next);
elPrev.addEventListener("click", prev);
```

```html
<button id="select-audio">Select Files</button>
<button id="prev">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
<audio id="audio" controls></audio>
<p id="title"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions  I will definitely use them to improve my cose, however your code gets the names of all selected audios and displays them together in the document, what I want is to display the name of the currently played song, once the song ends or gets switched the name updates to the new song, I fixed the problem with the help of the previous answer and I will use your suggestions to improve my code and free up memory, thank you so much 

Comment: @SamMO sorry for the mishap. Edited to update the song name on play()

Comment: @SamMO yes, I know that this answer might be hard to chew, but fixes many other issues you had in your code. Hope you'll be able to follow along, but if you'll have questions regarding some of it, feel free to ask.